# Linux machine log in Windows machine using "ssh"?

Tags: linux, ssh, window

I am in a company.

Ip of linux machine is 192.168.8.183,

Ip of my Windows machine is 172.16.22.53.

The linux machine and Windows mashine are real machine ,not the VM virtualbox.

First I installed cygwin .

And then I installed copssh and openssh-server for my Windows machine.But after try a lot,I uninstall copssh and openssh-server.

Nowonly cygwin exist!

After that restart my Windows machine.
And then I log in the linux machine using putty im my windows machine,and then use $ ssh sikaiwei@172.16.22.53 ,but some error appear :

```
[sikaiwei@login-0-11 ~]$ ssh sikaiwei@172.16.22.53
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
61:aa:6a:0d:85:da:bc:82:64:42:b6:56:3f:27:02:2b.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts:2
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Agent forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
X11 forwarding is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
[sikaiwei@login-0-11 ~]$
```

I find this:

```
Add correct host key in /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
```

So I go to /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts:

```
[sikaiwei@login-0-11 .ssh]$ vi known_hosts
192.168.8.183 ssh-rsa   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAr0OPxQ49Nvl9JxvUEKsFa0LraupPW
i3zShoBCiSNSgaiQZNA/7v6YCYovVV+Fyd1+AoIuAVN+17jiuiLc9Upxkqu3     
/BQnEZB1quDUFPLnNYXguentNmGDLeovrrzHCY8nfUNstxNOm 
/fGosu1kwmQT7MyWB2j2dhjgkf8k0NOsrZkBOoz4zwoLhvAs 
/N8zhiI+DKiJ3b6SSxPfr582FM2uEnsXB6jql4B2AONICxmPfU1nBhsSx0IaX+esOGDD9
Rfk03QPqPAgmDapqGbz6EhnUY3cIXt5JEpznkogM6gZoTNLB+fX878YHqRRkqzBUD
 4xhp5dlAQ+h5nCscK5GcFw==
 172.16.22.53 ssh-rsa     
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAAAgQDQxnLSG/xVy6jSMd2cyv+5G2pR8MrKOnlqJv+ppfl5Nb1CfKgrK8c
Q2BnlFuSJTnVWsBtc89812tGmLsaE2NaFVxDStAW0JoqO5W9IShT0hCRvcn9sAu3yS
ZQYYXZgJIG0dSR2YBUyNv+tqRQWSbWswGUKjVqOlRPQ/M6DTsLFCw==
```

I remove the line 2,but then:

```
[sikaiwei@login-0-11 .ssh]$ ssh sikaiwei@172.16.22.53
Warning: Permanently added '172.16.22.53' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
sikaiwei@172.16.22.53's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
 sikaiwei@172.16.22.53's password:
 Permission denied, please try again.
 sikaiwei@172.16.22.53's password:
 Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get to the bottom of this error and fix it.

The error basically means that the SSH Client recognises the IP address / hostname that you are trying to connect to, but that the keys associated with that box have changed.   If you are using DHCP that might explain the problem.

If you are confident that you are talking to the correct machine you can simply edit /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts and remove line 2.

If you want to always get rid of this message - for all hosts - and are OK with the risk of a Man in the middle attack, you can delete /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts and then symlink it to /dev/null with the command "ln -s /etc/null /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts".  This is not adviseable.

You can also "temporarily ignore" this file with the command "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null username@address

Comment: Should I  remove line 2 in /home/sikaiwei/.ssh/known_hosts?

Comment: Yes.  That will fix the problem until the IP address changes.  The question is why did error occur.  If you have rebuilt the machine or changed its IP address then its OK to do this.

Comment: It is ok!But new error appear(I reedit my question)

Comment: Ok, this means you can't log in because the server and client can't agree on authentication.  How were you planning on logging in ?  Using a password or a public/private key ?  Are you sure your password is correct and the account "sikaiwei" exists on the server - with that password ?

Comment: I want to use password logging in .I use the "sikaiwei" and the  password when I log in my Windows machine.

Comment: In my Windows machine,now noly cygwin exist and no openssh-server or other ssh exist.